# Settings in limits.conf can't affect process started by init.d script

Tags: linux, limit, file-descriptor

My host is redhat, default fd limit is 1024, and I added following lines in /etc/security/limits.conf :

```
*       soft    nofile  8192
*       hard    nofile  65535
```

After this, newly logged in shells have FD limit raised to 8192 correctly, but the processes started by init.d script doesn't have their fd limit raised, i.e. they still have the fd limit as 1024, only after I logged in and use service command to restart them, could their fd limit be raised to 8192.

So how can I make daemons started by init.d script to have the FD limit set in limits.conf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/security/limits.conf` is a configuration file for `pam authentication`. It sets limits for logged in users not for system processes:

From `man limits.conf`:

> The pam_limits.so module applies ulimit limits, nice priority and number of simultaneous login sessions limit to
>          user login sessions. This description of the configuration file syntax applies to the /etc/security/limits.conf file
>          and *.conf files in the /etc/security/limits.d directory.

Comment: Please also check this thread for more info: http://serverfault.com/questions/461465/how-to-increase-max-fd-limit-for-a-daemon-process-running-under-a-headless-user